# C# how to select past date using datetime picker

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

I need to get the value of the past date using datetimepicker event value changed.
Here's my code:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

private void dtpSelectDate_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();

    DataTable qwe = new DataTable();

    SqlDataAdapter asd = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "Select Distinct * from viewResult where Date= '" + d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "'", 
        con);

    asd.Fill(qwe);
    dgvReports.DataSource = qwe;

    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Noooo.. check out http://bobby-tables.com for reasons why you shouldn't do your SQLs like that. Always parameterize your queries!

Comment: I dont think I understand If the user selects March 10th, 2015, you want the date March 9th, 2015?

Comment: @ViníciusGabriel what i want is to see the data of the selected date like March 10th, 2015 and it will appear the data of that date

Comment: Please describe the action being taken, the expected result, and the actual result. It would also be useful to show where and how `d` changes in relation to the value of the date time picker, since `d` is the date you're passing to sql.

Comment: Search this site for *parameterized query*. If you change to using parameters, you can stop worrying about date formats and quotes, and not have to worry about SQL injection. It will also make what you're trying to do here much easier.

Comment: Are you asking how to get the `DateTime` value from a `DateTimePicker` control? Like this? `DateTime selectedDate = dtpSelectDate.Value;`? Or do you mean you want to save the value of the selected date *before* it changes? Or something else?

Comment: @RufusL yep just like that thanks you to and the others and it's working now.